# Unable to get legacy XML-RPC website working in IIS 8.0 integrated mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, xml-rpc

I have a legacy `.NET webservice` that is built on top of XML-RPC server library provided by cook-computing ( http://www.cookcomputing.com ), everything works fine in `Classic Mode` however when I try to migrate it to the `Integrated mode` it gives me an error as

> System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Requested Service not
>   found

Following are the contents of my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections/> 
   <appSettings file="c:\website\load.xml">
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="330301440" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" /> 
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add  name="TESLA" path="tesla.rem"  verb="*" type="System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http.HttpRemotingHandlerFactory, System.Runtime.Remoting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />        
    </handlers>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files> 
        <remove value="index.htm" />
        <remove value="index.html" />
        <remove value="Default.asp" />
        <remove value="Default.htm" />
        <remove value="iisstart.htm" />
        <remove value="default.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <machineKey validationKey="XXXX" decryptionKey="XXX" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" /> 
    <identity impersonate="false" />
    <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="stdole, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Security, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Services, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.Protocols, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.EnterpriseServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.ServiceProcess, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.RegularExpressions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <authorization> 
      <allow users="*" /> 
    </authorization>
    <trace enabled="false" requestLimit="10" pageOutput="false" traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="true" />  
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />  
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />    
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

What might be the problem here given that I am able to get it working in classic mode (after making appropriate changes)?

Edit ( Apr 12 2019 ): I found that the solution to this problem was to use "appcmd.exe" to migrate the site from classic to integrated mode and then to edit it manually because of the flaws in the tool.

Comment: If the call stack can be tracked down to that library, contact its vendor please. It is not surprising that something does not support integrated mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps  anyone else, I was able to get it working  by doing the following things.

1) Using  appcmd migrate config "sitename/" to migrate the site from classic mode to integrated mode.

2) Editing the "handler" tag  to get rid of invalid framework association
    preCondition="runtimeVersionv2.0"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>  
<configSections />
   <appSettings file="c:\website\load.xml">
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="330301440" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security> 
    <handlers>
        <add name="tesla.rem_*" path="tesla.rem" verb="*" type="X.API.tesla, api" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers> 
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" /> 
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>   
        <clear />
        <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="0" />
        <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-avg=15552001; includeSubDomains; preload" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>   
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />  
    <defaultDocument>
      <files> 
        <remove value="index.htm" />
        <remove value="index.html" />
        <remove value="Default.asp" />
        <remove value="Default.htm" />
        <remove value="iisstart.htm" />
        <remove value="default.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>   
    <pages validateRequest="false">
    </pages>
    <identity impersonate="false" />
    <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="stdole, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Security, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Services, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.Protocols, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.EnterpriseServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.ServiceProcess, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.RegularExpressions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>   
    <customErrors mode="On" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <trace enabled="false" requestLimit="10" pageOutput="false" traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="true" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```